# Multiple Api Gateway on single Serverless Fastify project

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, api-gateway, fastify

I would like to know if is possible to have multiple Api Gateways defined on serverless.yml template for a single project. The objective is to have some endpoints private for only VPC resources and others public with normal api key.

This is the actual serverless:

```
functions:
  app:
    handler: app/app.handler
    events:

      # Public secured routes
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          private: true
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          private: true

  external:
    handler: app/external.handler
    events:

      # Private routes
      - http:
          path: /external/
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          private: true

      - http:
          path: /external/{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          private: true
```

It's possible to have something like the endpointType provider's parameter? For example:

```
functions:
  ...
      # Public
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          private: true
          endpointType: EDGE

      # Private
      - http:
          path: /private/{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          private: false
          endpointType: PRIVATE
  ...
```

I tried to create two resources of type `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` but i dont know if those are referenceable to serverless functions:

```
    PublicApiGateway:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
      Properties:
        Name: "${self:provider.stage}-${self:service}-agw-public"
        Description: "Public API Gateway"
        EndpointConfiguration:
          Types:
            - EDGE
      DependsOn: app

    PrivateApiGateway:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
      Properties:
        Name: "${self:provider.stage}-${self:service}-agw-private"
        Description: "Private API Gateway"
        EndpointConfiguration:
          Types:
            - PRIVATE
      DependsOn: external
```